Pella three point patio door lock
My three point lock is in pieces. I would like to reconstruct it.  Is there a source for a schematic for a 20-30 year old Pella swinging door lock?

The manufacturer's installation instructions would be an obvious place to start. Most such can be found somewhere on the web these days

If you add a photo, the exact model might be identified, or repair instructions suggested.
